Importing entries with FeedMe (pagination) and using Blitz, triggers a full Blitz refresh, not only the changed entries being updated
Craft Pro: 4.11.5
Blitz: 4.23.0
Feed Me: 5.7.0
When the FeedMe import/update runs, and page 1 is finished, all the Blitz cached entries (for the secified section) are being refreshed. Not only the entries that we're being processed by this page import/update, but also the other entries not touched (yet).
When Blitz update is finished, the next FeedMe page import runs, and again Blitz will refresh all entries in our section.
I would expect that only the touched entries, and the entries were the touched ones are used, would be refreshed by Blitz.
Is this normal behaviour, or is there something wrong in our setup? How can i best approach the search for the cause and solution.
I understand, it's a very specific case, but any pointers are welcome!
Thank you in advance for your time, and best regards.
Jan

By default, Blitz will only refresh pages that track modified entries.
If you’re convinced this is a bug, please create an issue, providing a diagnostics report and ideally a reproducible demo site, and I can take a closer look.

Hi Ben, i think it is something like this, the section being updated, was also modified (added extra fields). Because i ran the paginated FeedMe import once more, and now the Blitz cache was logicly refreshed. Thank you for your response and anwser. When i have more time to create a reproducible demo site, i will do so. Best regards, Jan
